# Set Store Currency Based on Customer's accesing Country

Tags: php, magento

I want to set My store Currency Based on the customer country.

```
<?php
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
   echo $ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode; // Here i am getting the country code

   if($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode == 'US'){
       Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('USD'); // i tried this 
   }
?>
```

**Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('USD');**

I tried this but it is giving the following error.

[image]

Why is it giving an error ?

any Idea?

Comment: where have you written this code?

Comment: @RakeshShewale in index.php

Comment: Please refer http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/how-to-set-default-store-currency-based-on-visitor-country-in-magento/

Comment: where in index.php you put code? confirm above Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType); ?

Comment: @PrashantValanda Sorry for delay.. yes i placed that code just above to that line.