# Change Base Currency Programmatically

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am using Magento CE 1.9.1.0

I have one Magento website and with INR Base Currency.

And i have 2 stores in that the very first store is for Domestic Customers (India Customers), the second store is for International Customers(All cutomers except Indian Customers). This store switching, i am doing it in **index.php** based on customer Country(Getting Customer Country by Customer IP).

I just configured PayPal Payment Gateway in my Magento Store.

Before going to my question, i want share few things about Paypal PG, This Payment Gateway is only for International Customers and PayPal will not work for INR Currency.

If i am changing my Base Currency as USD or other than INR, the PayPal payment method is showing inside my Payment Methods, if the Base Currency is INR the PayPal Payment Method is not showing in Checkout Page.

Please check these images

1. Base Currency : INR

[image]

2. Base Currency : USD

[image]

I want to have Base Currency as INR because all of my products are uploading with INR and from my ERP i can't change that.

But i want this PayPal Payment Method as one of my Payment Option in My Store for International Customers.

Still looking for solution...

Any ideas ?

Comment: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/how-to-set-default-store-currency-based-on-visitor-country-in-magento/ Take a look @ it Naresh.

Comment: @Sundar because of this i can change current currency but i want i want to change Base Currency for Store 2 and from my ERP products are uploading with INR

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sorry guys,

editing core files is bad practice but for me this changes are taking me forward.

Here i found the solution,

```
Go to app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php
```

Change this array

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN','NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
```

To

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN','NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB','INR');
```

Another trick :

```
Go to app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php
```

Then change this function

```
public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
    {
  return $this->getConfig()->isCurrencyCodeSupported($currencyCode);
    }
```

To

```
public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
    {
    if($currencyCode == 'INR')
  {
   $currencyCode = 'USD';
  }
  return $this->getConfig()->isCurrencyCodeSupported($currencyCode);
    }
```

If you want you can override this.

Answer (score 1):

you can set base currency below code
this code put in your index file and your store currency will be change.

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode(‘USD’);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this long time back only please have look in to it . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890145/set-store-currency-based-on-customers-accesing-country

Comment: I have seen this, you have to put that code before "/* Store or website code */" this comment and try may be help to you.

Comment: Ok i will try that and let you know.

Comment: no Still it is not working, because of that i can set only current store currency, if i  am changing Base Currency (Other than INR) only PayPay PG is working.

Comment: Can you please verify your payment configuration your store view wise.

Comment: yes, i don't have any problem with configuration and if i change my Base Currency as USD PayPal PG is working fine.

Comment: ok, I need to see your current configuration, If you give your magento backend credential.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88076/discussion-between-naresh-and-simbeez).